# Oracle Edition required to use fuzzy operators

Tags: oracle

I've checked in the Oracle documentation etc but can't find any specific mention of what Version of Oracle 11.2 can use Fuzzy operators. 
In particular want to know if avaialable in Std Ed
Thanks

Comment: Did you see: http://oracle.su/docs/11g/text.112/e10945/query.htm

Answer (score 2):

The Oracle documentation includes the Licensing guide which explains the limitation of features by edition. [Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/license.112/e10594/editions.htm#BABDJGGI)

Anything which is not mentioned in the Licensing Guide is available in all editions.  Oracle Text is not mentioned (assuming that's what you mean by "fuzzy operators") so you can use it with SE.